# Trello.Net: how to access Action list?

Tags: c#, trello.net

I am using C# and Trello.Net package to extract Trello information. Trello.Net is great in getting almost everything that I need. However, I do run into a simple challenge and need help. How can I get the list of activity (action list) from a Card? I assume I can get the list from the Card so if it is not, please correct me.

Here is my snippet of code:

```
var results = trello.Search(_card.Name); //search the card by name    
var actionList = results.Actions;
```

I also try with the full set of Search parameters

```
var modelList = new List<ModelType> { ModelType.Actions };
var results = trello.Search(_card.Name, 100, null, modelList, null, false);
var actionList = results.Actions;
```

But the actionList is always empty.

Can someone please point me to the right direction in getting the list of actions?

Thanks,

Chi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all actions for a card this way:

```cs
var card = trello.Cards.WithId(cardId);
var actions = trello.Actions.ForCard(card);
```